# Why does AUCTeX have \autocite taking two arguments?

Tags: bibliographies, emacs, auctex

[image: output]

Obviously, compiling this just yields

> A sample citation: [1, p. 1]arg two?no arg three.

so `\autocite` itself definitely isn't using the argument.
Why is this so, and how can it be fixed?

Note the red `\` when only one argument is given:

[image: output]

Comment: It should be noted that this behaviour is not reproduced with `\autocites`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently the extra opening brace was the culprit. Which can be easily fixed by changing `line 306` and `line 307` of `font-latex.el`, saving the file, and compiling AUCTeX again.

So replace the following in line 306

`("autocite" "*[{{")`

to

`("autocite" "[[{")`

and line 307

`("Autocite" "*[{{")`

to

`("Autocite" "[[{")`

[image]

Comment: Just created a [PR](https://github.com/giordano/auctex/pull/1) for @giordano to look over (I just hope I sent the patch to the right place.) Thanks!

Comment: glad the answer resolved the issue, take care

Comment: @SeanAllred I already fixed this upstream in July `;-)`.

Comment: @giordano I wonder then why ELPA hasn't been updated, then… is it waiting for emacs 24.4? (I've heard it's now feature-frozen.)

Comment: It seems GNU ELPA will use only AUCTeX stable releases.

Comment: @giordano I haven't used ELPA for years now. I always download it from https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/download-for-unix.html

Comment: @giordano `context.el` needs revision, then this one, I wonder how many more loose ends are there, for I only use a handful of them.

Comment: Isn't the legendary David Kastrup responsible to update it accordingly, regardless of ELPA or emacs releases?

Comment: @doed Unfortunately, none of the active developers use ConTeXt.  If you are able to improve `context.el` your help would be greatly appreciated!  David Kastrup last made a commit to AUCTeX more than five years ago, but he is still active on the mailing list.